# ValueError in sklearn: shapes not aligned

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am attempting to return the test scores I ran through my program, but no matter what I try, I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-4b49cb58c813> in <module>()
----> 1 print(model_final.score(X_train, y_train))
      2 print(model_final.score(X_test, y_test))

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    140         return ret
    141     else:
--> 142         return np.dot(a, b)
    143 
    144 

ValueError: shapes (353,10) and (172,) not aligned: 10 (dim 1) != 172 (dim 0)
```

The full code can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UBeGn3YhU4zmz26HhGXQTEfsOQwpRAKX).

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the line

```
model_final = model
```

This statement will not create a replica of `model`, it just does a [shallow copy](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/) so when you change your `model` even the `model_final` will get changed. To avoid this you need to do a `deepcopy` as

```
from copy import deepcopy
model_final = deepcopy(model)
```

this will do a `deep copy` and whatever changes you make to `model` will not affect `model_final`.